# Java program runs in eclipse but not in when exported

Tags: java

im writing a program and it works correctly in eclipse, but when I export it it doesn't run at at all. I know that it is exporting correctly because i can remove a bit of the code and have it work. Here is the troublesome code :

```
 String FilePath = newPath.getParent() + "\\" + "JapaneseRotations.txt";

        Scanner s = new Scanner(new File(FilePath));
        s.next();
        int XSize = Integer.parseInt(s.nextLine().trim());
        s.next();
        int YSize = Integer.parseInt(s.nextLine().trim());
        s.next();
        int FontSize = Integer.parseInt(s.nextLine().trim());
        s.nextLine();
        s.nextLine();
        while (s.hasNextLine()){
            studentNames.add(s.nextLine());
        }
        s.close();
```

Anyone know how to fix this problem?

Comment: It is outputting that it can't find the specified file, even though its the exact file that was in the Eclispe folder. I have also ensured that it is in fact there

Comment: What is your path?

Comment: What is the problem here ?....Please share the output that you are getting while you are running the above program outside IDE

Comment: Is the file being exported with the jar file you are exporting? When you run `java -jar ...` then the path of the files may be different than in the IDE. You should output the absolute file path of the file you expect to find before loading it. That way you can see, where the file is expected, and whether it is actually there. Don't do `new Scanner` immediately, but store the `new File` to a variable. Then output the absolute path.